# Angularjs how to set the default value for select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have the following object:

```
defaults = {
0 : {
    id : 10,
    value : "string 1"
    },
1 : {
    id : 22,
    value : "string 2"
    }
}
```

I want to iterate over this object and display it as a select box.

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="obj.id as obj.value for obj in defaults">
   <option value="">---Select option-----</option>
</select>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to select 'string 2' by default. But it does not work.
The problem I have is the fact the selectedValue is a string:

```
$scope.selectedValue = "string 2";
```

From what I learned from the documentation the selectedValue must be the same object. But unfortunately, it is not possible. In my case selectedValue must be a string.
In other words I need to operate with the name of the option only, I don't care about id.
I tried to use ng-repeat. It even works but displays an empty option and I don't think using ng-repeat is a good way to do it.

Any advice will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: If you want the selectedValue to contain the value, and not the ID, then you should not use `obj.id as obj.value`, but `obj.value as obj.value`

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I need. Please re-post your comment as reply. I will accept it.

Comment: Do you want the entire object of the selected option or only the string value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `selectedValue` variable to contain the value, and not the ID, then you should not use `obj.id as obj.value`, but `obj.value as obj.value`.

Answer (score 2):

Selected value should be id;

```
 $scope.selectedValue = 22;
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w9mQ8/)

**EDIT:**

change template

```
 <select ng-model="selectedValue" >
   <option value="">---Select option-----</option>
   <option ng-selected="selectedValue == obj.value" value="{{obj.value}}" ng-repeat="obj in defaults">{{obj.value}}</option>
 </select>
```

see Updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w9mQ8/2/)

Comment: Please see me above. selectedValue is always a string. This is how api works and I don't have an ability to alter it. It returns just the name of the selected option e.g. "string 2" and the list of options.

Comment: defaults is a object or array ?

Comment: Defaults is an object.

Comment: is defaults rendering select box ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I admit this may be weird enough and may be api will be changed later (i'm not responsive for it),but for now it should work this way.

Comment: @user3174320 Accept the answer please if this is the solution you went for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpreted the documentation.

Selected value should refer to a value of the same object, not be an object itself.

Thus, you can set the default value as :

```
$scope.selectedValue = $scope.defaults[1].value;
```

That way, the default value will be set - it does not matter if the value is a string or a number.

Comment: Please see my comments to the reply above. I cannot set selectedValue.  selectedValue is _always_ a string returned by API. defaults is an object returned by ip. So, the comparision must be done by the value, not by id.

Comment: @user3174320 The default value does not work that way. What you will have to do is, once the API returns the string, loop through the `default` object's properties and when the value matches, assign that property value to `selectedValue`. Don't attach the value returned by the API directly to `selectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-repeat with options you need to use  on-last-repeat on your options tag. For example
       select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="usertypes.SelectedId"

option ng-repeat="option in usertypes.AvailableOptions" value="{{option.Id}}" ng-selected="option.Id === usertypes.SelectedId" on-last-repeat>{{option.Name}}

select